# Comparing Index Values in Python so that I'm Not Constantly Repeating If Statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, conditional-statements

I'm working on an application in Python that takes a list provided by a program and attempts to process the text for closed captioning.  I’m using IBM Watson to transcribe audio files, then return a JSON with the transcribed words and a timestamp that notes the start time and end time of each word.  Here is a small example of what that data looks like.  (NOTE: I've simplified the JSON response so that I only highlight the portion of data applicable to this question)

```
section = [
    ['for', 5.77, 5.92],
    ['the', 5.92, 6.03],
    ['longest', 6.03, 6.53],
    ['time', 6.53, 7.01],
    ['only', 7.23, 7.56],
    ['a', 7.56, 7.64],
    ['handful', 7.64, 8.2],
    ['of', 8.2, 8.3],
    ['people', 8.3, 8.72],
    ['would', 8.72, 8.88],
    ['know', 8.88, 9.01],
    ['the', 9.01, 9.14],
    ['data', 9.14, 9.56],
    ['that', 9.59, 9.73],
    ['was', 9.73, 9.84],
    ['collected', 9.84, 10.39],
    ['by', 10.39, 10.55],
    ['a', 10.55, 10.63],
    ['specific', 10.63, 11.18],
    ['application', 11.18, 11.91]
]
```

I’m only interested in the words (0-index0 and the start time (1-index) of each list in 'section'.

For closed captioning, my goal is to capture a collection of words for every 2.5 seconds and only mark the time stamp of the first word within that set.  So, in the example provided above, the first index provided would be my “zero-marker” and every word that followed within a 2.5 second time frame would be collected into a phrase.  Any data afterwards would follow the same logic – for all data, group words that exist within 2.5 seconds from each other and mark the time stamp of the first word in the set.

However, since I cannot predict the duration of the files nor how Watson will transcribe them – I’m having difficulty figuring out the best way to handle identifying groups of words by the 2.5 second requirement.

Here’s what I’ve written:

```
    # use the tag variable to identify the start time of the
    # first word outside of 2.5 seconds
    tag = 0

    # use the first index's start time as the benchmark for 2.5 second duration
    benchmark = section[0][1]

    for i in range(len(section)):
        if abs(benchmark - section[i][1]) < 2.5:
            # do stuff
            foo(bar)

            # update tag variable to identify first start time
            # for word outside of 2.5 seconds.  This will
            # continue to update until the if statement is no longer true.
            if (i + 1) < len(section):
                tag = section[i + 1][1]

        else:
            # use tag to create new benchmark
            benchmark = tag
            if abs(benchmark - section[i][1]) < 2.5:
                # do stuff
```

Where I'm struggling is that I would have to keep writing the function this way for however long the transcription is -- what seems like an endless series of potential if statements.  In other words, I would still have to handle what to do with words that didn't fall within the first 2.5 seconds, the second set of 2.5 seconds, so on and so forth.  I feel like there should be a more eloquent and efficient way of doing this.

My goal would be to ultimately process the text so that it looked similar to what I've listed below, but would work no matter how long the list / time frame was.

```
['for the longest time only a handful of', 5.77],
['people would know the data that was collected by a specific', 8.3],
['application', 11.18]
```

Any assistance, guidance, advice, etc. would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that iterates through 2.5 second intervals in the list and outputs the phrases. Does it work for your needs?

```
    start = section[0][1]
    end = section[-1][1]

    for mark in range(0, int((end-start)/2.5)+1):
        phrase = [(x[0],x[1]) for x in section if int((x[1]-start)/2.5)==mark]
        print([' '.join((word for word, mark in phrase)), phrase[0][1]])
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you!  I haven’t seen the method you used for line 5 implemented before. Good to know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This a [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem). There's

- the producer: the `section` sequence that yields individual items
- the consumer: the logic that accumulates the incoming items into a chunk and returns the chunk once it's ready.

  - Since this algorithm returns chunks one by one as is goes, it lends itself naturally to be a generator.

Since the producer is expressible as a single loop statement, we can place the consumer into the loop body -- but have to initialize it before the first iteration (so, the initialization code is going to be duplicated).

The tricky part is to get checks in an iteration in the right order so that we don't have to do any other operation in multiple places in the code:

- First check if we're just accumulating or returning, too.
- If returning, return the chunk and reset it.
- Then, append the item if the chunk is not empty or initialize it if it is
- Finally, when the sequence is over, return the last pending chunk if there's any.

`None` is more convenient to indicate that the chunk is not initialized than some specific value: 1) it's quickly checked for with truth test; 2) we had to duplicate the initialization code, so avoided duplicating some custom value; 3) there doesn't exist a "magic" initial value<sup>1</sup> for the item.

```
def gen_captions(section):
    item = None
    for word, start, _ in section:
        if item:
            if start - item['time'] >= 2.5:
                yield item
                item = None
            else:
                item['phrase']+=' '+word
        if not item:
            item = {'phrase':word,'time':start}            
    else:
        if item: yield item
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Some value concocted in such a way that it would pass checks the expected way and would be automatically overwritten with a "normal" value on the first iteration.

In some algorithms, such a value exists: e.g. when selecting the maximum number, the initial result could be set to the lowest possible number. Here, we never overwrite `time`, so "automatic overwriting" is not possible.</sub>